how to add parentheses in the chess moves using xskak
I have a very simple question but I am not able to find the answer. How can I try
22... N(g7)f5  using the xskak package. This notation means that the knight may go both g7 and f5 squares. For example, if I have the following code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xskak}

\begin{document}

\variation{22...N(g7)f5}

\end{document}

the output would be

which is not what I am seeking for it. I just want to have those parentheses in the chess moves as is in the code.
Many thanks for your help.

sorry but the pgn parsing imho doesn't support that. You could do something like {\variationstyle22\bmove{N(g7)f5}}

@UlrikeFischer, many thanks for your comments. It helped me a lot. What shall I do if I want to have it with the commands \variation[invar] or \variation[outvar] ?
